# Does macOS have something like Linux's binfmt_misc feature?

Tags: macos

Linux has *[binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)* which allows arbitrary executable file formats to be recognized and passed to certain user space applications. Does macOS have a similar feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, macOS does not come with a similar feature.

If you're interested in adding it yourself, you can could take a look at this project:

https://github.com/georghe-crihan/imgact_linux

It is a kernel extension that extends the kernel's `exec_shell_imgact()` function to recognize other file types (namely Linux ELF binaries) and pass them to a user space application to be executed. The source code is available, so it could potentially be tweaked and extended to provide functionality similar to binfmt_misc.